# Pull single file on server

Tags: git, version-control, github, putty

I have committed several files on GitHub but I want to pull only single file on server. How can I do that using PuTTY?

Comment: Did you navigate to the file on the github web interface and click "RAW" on the upper right corner? You can use this url to download to get the content of the file in question.

Comment: Pulling in git means fetch+merge. And you fetch commits, never single files. There is no way to get a single file from a remote git repository, but see Alex's answer for how to get a single file from GitHub web interface.

Comment: I want to merge changes. Its not like downloading that file, downloading is so simple.

Comment: @user1338062: Write that as an answer if you are confident.

Comment: I am not sure if I (or the other commenters) have understood correctly what you really want to do - can you elaborate the original question a bit?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
git fetch
git checkout -m revision  -- the/file/you/want
git add the/file/you/want
git commit
```

checkout the file you want and merge it with the current one

Answer (score 2):

You can grab a single file via this URL:

```
https://raw.github.com/USER/PROJECT/BRANCH/FILE
```

Comment: I want to merge changes on server like using svn its `svn update filename`

Comment: OK, I see -- misunderstood your question.

Comment: good tip though.  got me an answer i wasn't looking for but helps me out.