# Git: How to pull a single file from a server repository in Git?

Tags: git, git-merge, git-pull, git-fetch

I am working on a site with a server running Git. I am using Git for deployment (not GitHub). This was set up prior to my involvement using a [hook method](https://danbarber.me/using-git-for-deployment/), and I referred to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11245424/pull-single-file-on-server) and entered the commands below, but it didn't work.

How do I pull a single file from the server? For instance, if I wanted to update my local file index.php? `git pull index.php`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to pull just one file in Git?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16230838/is-it-possible-to-pull-just-one-file-in-git)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to checkout only one file from git repository?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2466735/how-to-checkout-only-one-file-from-git-repository)

Answer (score 301, accepted):

### Short Answer

It is possible to do (in the deployed repository):

```
git fetch --all
// git fetch will download all the recent changes, but it will not put it in your current checked out code (working area).
```

Followed by:

```
git checkout origin/master -- path/to/file
// git checkout <local repo name (default is origin)>/<branch name> -- path/to/file will checkout the particular file from the downloaded changes (origin/master).
```

### Full Example

```
$ cd /project/directory

$ git branch
* develop
```

check the remote name

```
$ git remote -v
origin git@github.com:abc/123.git
```

Confirmed it's `origin` and

I am on branch `develop` and need a file from branch `main`

File i need is `src/scss/main.scss`

```
git fetch --all
```

```
git checkout origin/main -- src/scss/main.scss
```

Comment: Thank you. So what do you mean by `<revision>`? the file name? And if my file is in the root directory would that mean i have to type: `git checkout -m index.php index.php`?

Comment: Does it hast to be`*origin*/master` or can it be from any remote? Is the whole history pulled into my repo or does the file seem to appear magically?

Comment: If you get this error "did not match any file(s) known to git": "path/to/file" should not be the copy of the path that you get from the file location on GitHub, meaning "repoName/fileName", you should get rid of "repoName/" and then it will work.

Comment: @BernhardDöbler it can be any branch from remote :)

Comment: @Eduard that is correct, it is your local path-- i would recommend using relative as you stated. You can use `pwd` in unix/linux systems to 'print working directory'. this will show you where you are for absolute paths

Comment: Hi I am new to git, I tried with this it's working  fine. But I have a doubt, git fetch  command will fetch the changes from remote but will not merge the changes to working copy. But while using fetch command and checkout  command(the solution you provided) how the changes are merged to the working copy, as we have not hit any merge command. I know that checkout command to switch the branch. need your  help @chrismillah

Comment: @RajanikantaPradhan with that specific command for checkout, you are checking out a specific file into your working directory,  not anything else. Does that help?

Comment: How make it renamed once.. what git command line of it?

Comment: Why  we are not doing `git fetch --all` instead of `git fetch`?

Comment: Good call @alper

Comment: Thanks, dude!
By me works it:    `git checkout origin/main -- name_of_file`

Answer (score 40):

```
git fetch --all
git checkout origin/master -- <your_file_path>
git add <your_file_path>
git commit -m "<your_file_name> updated"
```

This is assuming you are pulling the file from origin/master.

Comment: Simple and efficient, thanks

Answer (score 22):

This can be the solution:

```
git fetch

git checkout origin/master -- FolderPathName/fileName
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 14):

I was looking for slightly different task, but this looks like what you want:

```
git archive --remote=$REPO_URL HEAD:$DIR_NAME -- $FILE_NAME |
tar xO > /where/you/want/to/have.it
```

I mean, if you want to fetch `path/to/file.xz`, you will set `DIR_NAME` to `path/to` and `FILE_NAME` to `file.xz`.
So, you'll end up with something like

```
git archive --remote=$REPO_URL HEAD:path/to -- file.xz |
tar xO > /where/you/want/to/have.it
```

And nobody keeps you from any other form of unpacking instead of `tar xO` of course (It was me who need a pipe here, yeah).

Answer (score 7):

This scenario comes up when you -- or forces greater than you -- have **mangled a file** in your local repo and you just want to restore a fresh copy of the latest version of it from the repo. Simply deleting the file with /bin/rm (not git rm) or renaming/hiding it and then issuing a `git pull` will not work: git notices the file's absence and assumes you probably want it gone from the repo (`git diff` will show all lines deleted from the missing file).

`git pull` not restoring locally missing files has always frustrated me about git, perhaps since I have been influenced by other version control systems (e.g. [svn update](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.update.html) which I believe *will* restore files that have been locally hidden).

`git reset --hard HEAD` is an alternative way to restore the file of interest as it throws away any uncommitted changes you have. However, as noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9529078/how-do-i-use-git-reset-hard-head-to-revert-to-a-previous-commit), git reset is is a potentially dangerous command if you have any other uncommitted changes that you care about.

The `git fetch ... git checkout` strategy noted above by @chrismillah is a nice surgical way to restore the file in question.

Answer (score 2):

Try using:

```
git checkout branchName -- fileName
```

Ex:

```
git checkout master -- index.php
```

Comment: Attention: "git checkout master -- index.php" this dont do checkout from server, but from local git database from last pull.

Answer (score 1):

just do git checkout / -- path/to/file

Ex.: `git checkout origin/staging -- src/main.ts`

Answer (score 0):

```
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/[USER-NAME]/[REPOSITORY-NAME]/[BRANCH-NAME]/[FILE-PATH]
```

Ex. https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vipinbihari/apana-result/master/index.php

> Through this you would get the contents of an individual file as a row
>   text. You can download that text with wget.

Ex. https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vipinbihari/apana-result/master/index.php

Comment: The OP specifically indicated in the question that he is not using github.

Answer (score 0):

This windows batch works regardless of whether or not it's on GitHub. I'm using it because it shows some stark caveats. **You'll notice that the operation is slow and traversing hundreds of megabytes of data**, so don't use this method if your requirements are based on available bandwidth/R-W memory.

**sparse_checkout.bat**

```
pushd "%~dp0"
if not exist .\ms-server-essentials-docs mkdir .\ms-server-essentials-docs
pushd .\ms-server-essentials-docs
git init
git remote add origin -f https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/windowsserverdocs.git
git config core.sparseCheckout true
(echo EssentialsDocs)>>.git\info\sparse-checkout
git pull origin master
```

=>

> C:\Users\user name\Desktop>sparse_checkout.bat
>
> C:\Users\user name\Desktop>pushd "C:\Users\user name\Desktop\"
>
> C:\Users\user name\Desktop>if not exist .\ms-server-essentials-docs
>   mkdir .\ms-server-essentials-docs
>
> C:\Users\user name\Desktop>pushd .\ms-server-essentials-docs
>
> C:\Users\user name\Desktop\ms-server-essentials-docs>git init
>   Initialized empty Git repository in C:/Users/user
>   name/Desktop/ms-server-essentials-docs/.git/
>
> C:\Users\user name\Desktop\ms-server-essentials-docs>git remote add
>   origin -f https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/windowsserverdocs.git
>   Updating origin remote: Enumerating objects: 97, done. remote:
>   Counting objects: 100% (97/97), done. remote: Compressing objects:
>   100% (44/44), done. remote: Total 145517 (delta 63), reused 76 (delta
>   53), pack-reused 145420 Receiving objects: 100% (145517/145517),
>   751.33 MiB | 32.06 MiB/s, done. Resolving deltas: 100% (102110/102110), done. From
>   https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/windowsserverdocs  * [new branch]
>   1106-conflict      -> origin/1106-conflict  * [new branch]
>   FromPrivateRepo    -> origin/FromPrivateRepo  * [new branch]
>   PR183              -> origin/PR183  * [new branch]
>   conflictfix        -> origin/conflictfix  * [new branch]
>   eross-msft-patch-1 -> origin/eross-msft-patch-1  * [new branch]
>   master             -> origin/master  * [new branch]          patch-1
>   -> origin/patch-1  * [new branch]          repo_sync_working_branch -> origin/repo_sync_working_branch  * [new branch]
>   shortpatti-patch-1 -> origin/shortpatti-patch-1  * [new branch]
>   shortpatti-patch-2 -> origin/shortpatti-patch-2  * [new branch]
>   shortpatti-patch-3 -> origin/shortpatti-patch-3  * [new branch]
>   shortpatti-patch-4 -> origin/shortpatti-patch-4  * [new branch]
>   shortpatti-patch-5 -> origin/shortpatti-patch-5  * [new branch]
>   shortpatti-patch-6 -> origin/shortpatti-patch-6  * [new branch]
>   shortpatti-patch-7 -> origin/shortpatti-patch-7  * [new branch]
>   shortpatti-patch-8 -> origin/shortpatti-patch-8
>
> C:\Users\user name\Desktop\ms-server-essentials-docs>git config
>   core.sparseCheckout true
>
> C:\Users\user name\Desktop\ms-server-essentials-docs>(echo
>   EssentialsDocs ) 1>>.git\info\sparse-checkout
>
> C:\Users\user name\Desktop\ms-server-essentials-docs>git pull origin
>   master
>   From https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/windowsserverdocs 
>   * branch                master     -> FETCH_HEAD

Answer (score 0):

Now is possible and easy:

```bash
git archive --remote=git://git.organization.com/repo.git HEAD:path/in/repo filename | tar -x
```