# How can i Pull a single file change from github?

Tags: python, linux, github, testing, web-development-server

Hello Stackoverflow and hello to all the developers .
Sir actually i am running in a problem .
I've hosted my new blog website on a linux vps , and when i hosted that it was just a bare minimum ,
now it's running perfectly on that vps and on my computer i am trying to add more features to it . but there is a problem when i push all changes to github and pull that changes to that vps it will changing my settings file , which is extremely important . now i am looking for a solution that i can pull single file changes not entire .
for example

i made image responsive in style.css file okay and push that change to github
how can i download that single change, single file change or that single file (style.css) to that vps?

if you will help me i will be very gladful to you

Comment: That's not what git was designed for. Consider to have multiple setting files or not tracking the settings in git.

Comment: How can i do that , well i would like to tell you that i am developing that project using django and python. how can i ignore settings.py commit changing? please share me the details

Answer (score 1):

```
git fetch --all
git checkout origin/master -- <your_file_path>
git add <your_file_path>
git commit -m "<your_file_name> updated"
```

First checkout to branch from where you want to pull.

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to this question: [Git: How to pull a single file from a server repository in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28375418/git-how-to-pull-a-single-file-from-a-server-repository-in-git)
So..
git fetch
then
git checkout (-p|--patch) [] [--] […​]
see https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout