# Git - sync only one file

Tags: git, github, pull, repo

I got my project on github made up of several files. I work on it locally on my machine and push the updates to the github repo.

I’d like to create now a new folder on a different dir on my machine, in which I want to pull a single file from that repo every time it gets updated.

How would I proceed to set up this new folder to have the aforementioned functionality?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [Git: How to pull a single file from a server repository in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28375418/git-how-to-pull-a-single-file-from-a-server-repository-in-git) Might be the answer for you?

Comment: There are two "repo"s here: one on your laptop (well, you didn't say "laptop" but I use that to help distinguish it from the remote server machine), and one on the server. For this "new folder on [your laptop]", should that be a third *Git* repo, or just a folder? Which "that repo" do you care about being updated, just your own, or the one on the server, or both?